# How can Docker run distros with different kernels?

Tags: linux-kernel, docker, linux-distro

How can docker run on a Debian host maybe an OpenSUSE in a container? It uses different kernel, with separated modules. Also older Debian versions have used older kernels, so how can run it on a kernel version 3.10+ ? Older kernels have only older built in functions, how can an old distro manage new features?
What is "the trick" in it?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> How can docker run on a Debian host maybe an OpenSUSE in a container

Because the kernel is the same and will support the Docker engine to run all those container images: the host kernel should be 3.10 or more, but its [list of **system calls**](http://linux.die.net/man/2/syscalls) is fairly stable.

See "[Architecting Containers: Why Understanding User Space vs. Kernel Space Matters](http://rhelblog.redhat.com/2015/07/29/architecting-containers-part-1-user-space-vs-kernel-space/)":

> 1. Applications contain business logic, but rely on system calls.
> 2. Once an application is compiled, the set of system calls that an application uses (i.e. relies upon) is embedded in the binary (in higher level languages, this is the interpreter or JVM).
> 3. Containers don’t abstract the need for the user space and kernel space to share a common set of system calls.
> 4. In a containerized world, this user space is bundled up and shipped around to different hosts, ranging from laptops to production servers.
> 5. Over the coming years, this will create challenges.

[image: https://rhelblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/user-space-vs-kernel-space-simple-container.png?w=584&h=231]

> From time to time new system calls are added, and old system calls are deprecated; this should be considered when thinking about the lifecycle of your container infrastructure and the applications that will run within it.

See also "[Why kernel version doesn't match Ubuntu version in a Docker container?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643847/why-kernel-version-doesnt-match-ubuntu-version-in-a-docker-container#comment924535_643958)":

> There's no kernel inside a container. Even if you install a kernel, it won't be loaded when the container starts. The very purpose of a container is to isolate processes without the need to run a new kernel.

Comment: I think that the above does not fully answer the question. While I totally agree that the referenced links provide good explaination why the containers don't spawn their own kernel we might actually want to spawn a container which possibly relies on a specific kernel version. I think docker even when running on a linux host could have a mode where you could choose the kernel version.

Comment: That diagram is incorrect and misleading: the "container" part isn't in user space at all. The container configuration changes how _the kernel_ responds to system calls, e.g., if you `open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY)`, which of many files known to the kernel is actually opened? From the user space point of view, the process is not different from a "non-containerized" process.

Answer (score 138):

Docker never uses a different kernel: the kernel is always your host kernel.

If your host kernel is "compatible enough" with the software in the container you want to run it will work; otherwise, it won't.

**"Containers" Are Just Process Configuration**

The key thing to understand is that a Docker container is *not* a virtual machine: it doesn't create a new virtual computer on which to run the software. Instead, Docker starts processes in your existing OS, just like you start new processes from the command line.

The difference between a "containerized" process and an ordinary process is the restrictions put on the containerized process and the changes to how it sees the environment around it. (These are passed on to any child processes started by the containerized process.) Typical restrictions and changes include:

- Instead of using the host's root filesystem, mount a different filesystem on `/` (usually one supplied with the container's image). Parts of the host filesystem may be mounted underneath the new process' root filesystem, e.g. by using `docker run -v /u/myprogram-data:/var/data/myprogram` so that when the containerized process reads or writes `/var/data/myprogram/file` this reads/writes `/u/myprogram-data/file` in the host filesystem.
- Create a separate process space for the containerized process so that it can see only itself and its children (with `ps` or similar commands), but cannot see other processes running on the host.
- Create a separate user namespace so that the users in the container are different from those in the host: e.g., UID 1234 in the containerized process will not be the same as UID 1234 for non-containerized
- Create a separate set of network interfaces with their own IP addresses, often using a "virtual router" and address translation between those and the host network interfaces. (E.g., the host, when it receives a packet on port 8080, forwards it to port 80 on the container processes' virtual network interface.)

All of this is done by facilities built into the kernel; you can do any of it yourself without Docker if you write a program to do the appropriate setup and set the appropriate parameters when it starts a new process.

**Compatibility**

So what does "compatible enough" mean? It depends on what requests the program makes of the kernel (system calls) and what features it expects the kernel to support. Some programs make requests that will break things; others don't. For example, on an Ubuntu 18.04 (kernel 4.19) or similar host:

- `docker run centos:7 bash` works fine.
- `docker run centos:6 bash` fails with exit code 139, meaning it terminated with a segmentation violation signal; this is because the 4.19 kernel doesn't support something that that build of `bash` tried to do.
- `docker run centos:6 ls` works fine because it's not making a request the kernel can't handle, as `bash` was.

If you try `docker run centos:6 bash` on an older kernel, say 4.9 or earlier, you'll find it will work fine. (At least as far as I tested it.)

Comment: I recently heard an expression that sums this up nicely imo: 'Docker is just a bunch of linux kernelisms.' Refering to namespaces, cgroups ...

Comment: @erikbozic To be more precise: it's the Linux kernel that "containerizes" processes, and Docker is a system that lets you create, store and recall Linux kernel process configurations. (And also handily stores filesystem images.)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot in Docker it uses the hosts kernel.
However, you can use virtual hosts on the host machine to do this.
As long as the virtualisation settings of the system and cpu support nested virtualisation.

1. Setup a virtual machine for each Linux/Kernel version.
2. Then install docker within each VM.
3. Then build and run containers in docker under the VM with the required Kernel version.