# difference between host and docker container

Tags: docker, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia-docker

I have been trying to train a 3DCNN network with a specific architecture. I wanted to create a dockerfile with all the steps necessary to have the network working. The issue is that If I run the neural network network in the host I have no problem, everything works fine. But doing almost the same on a docker container I always get the "segmentation fault (core dumped)" error.

Both installations are not exactly the same but the variations (maybe some extra package installed) shouldn't be a problem, right? Besides I don't have any error until it starts iterating, so it seems like is a memory problem. The GPU works on the docker container and is the same GPU as the host. the python code is the same.

The Docker container neural network network start training with the data but on the epoch 1 it gets the "segmentation fault (core dumped)".

So my question is the following: Is it possible to have critical differences between the host and a docker container even if they have exactly the same packages installed? Especially with relation to tensorflow and GPU. Because the error must be from outside the code, given that the code works in a similar environment.

Hope I explained myself enough to give the idea of my question, thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A docker image will resolve, at runtime, will resolve its system calls by the host kernel.
See "[How can Docker run distros with different kernels?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32842491/6309)".

In your case, your Error is

```
Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1, SSE4.2
```

See "[How to compile Tensorflow with SSE4.2 and AVX instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41293077/6309)"
(referenced by [`tensorflow/tensorflow` issue 8037](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8037))

You could try and build an image from a [Tensorflow built from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources), using a [docker multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/).

Comment: Ty, I will check that out tomorrow.

Comment: but, is it possible to compile Tensorflow with SSE4.2 and AVX instructions inside a dockerfile? I have been looking for dockerfiles that do that but I have no success, do you know any good one? Thank you.

Comment: @DiegoOrellana Not sure yet: can you ask a new question for that specific part?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504972/make-a-dockerfile-that-compiles-a-tensorflow-binary-to-use-sse4-1-sse4-2-and-a)