# Make a Dockerfile that compiles a Tensorflow binary to use: SSE4.1, SSE4.2 and AVX instructions

Tags: docker, tensorflow, cpu, sse4

So, one of the porpuses of docker is to easily deploy an environment to test software right? Can anybody tell me how to compile a Tensorflow binary to use: SSE4.1, SSE4.2 on a docker file?. Can anybody point me to a docker file that does that? if it is possible at all?

In summary, two questions:

- Is it possible to have a docker file that compiles a Tensorflow binary to use: SSE4.1, SSE4.2 (and GPU, I have only found one or the other)
- Can you tell me where I can found a docker file that does that or a good tutorial?

*"The purpose of this question is to avoid the following scenario: Where the host setup work but the docker set up doesn't work because Tensorflow was not compiled in a particular way."* Like the image below.[image]

Comment: Are you aware of this [dockerfile](https://github.com/PipelineAI/pipeline/blob/master/package/tensorflow/072355e-a44fd6d/Dockerfile)?

Comment: @Patwie Yes, thank you. But that dockerfile doesn't work for me, it throws errors when I build the image. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Patwie It says that the BAZEL_VERSION is too old, I changed it, then it started to throw more errors. So I find myself debugging a dockerfile which is against the main idea of a dockerfile. For that reason I started to doubt if it is possible at all to do that, maybe compiling the Tensorflow in a certain way depends somehow on the host, even if  it is done in a dockerfile. Did I explain myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The working example of such Dockerfile that can be used as a starting point is there: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/docker (see `README.md` for details).

More accurately, it is a set of parameterized Docker files, the build is started with `parameterized_docker_build.sh`. An example of a command that successfully compiles TensorFlow inside Docker is:

```
export TF_DOCKER_BUILD_IS_DEVEL=YES
export TF_DOCKER_BUILD_TYPE=CPU
export TF_DOCKER_BUILD_PYTHON_VERSION=PYTHON3
export TF_DOCKER_BUILD_DEVEL_BRANCH=master
tensorflow/tools/docker/parameterized_docker_build.sh
```

For the purpose of building TensorFlow with custom flags use `TF_DOCKER_BUILD_IS_DEVEL=YES` as non-devel Docker files just downloads precompiled Docker binaries from the server.

TensorFlow team just started to [build development Docker images with AVX](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/96dd8c99688290f90b9826af516b2c12d280c0ee) recently.

For SSE [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). You can modify bazel command line in your local copy of https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel.

PS. For non-devel TensorFlow build with custom options you could look at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/ci_build.

Comment: This link has everything I was looking for: https://github.com/mind/wheels