# Are there any service mesh implementations like Istio that support LXC containers?

Tags: kubernetes, lxc, servicemesh

I am trying to learn about service mesh architectures. I understand that the service mesh implementations typically inject an agent or a proxy inside a Kubernetes pod to achieve service-to-service communication.
Referring to [Can Kubernetes manage LXC containers without LXD daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448030/can-kubernetes-manage-lxc-containers-without-lxd-daemon/63483016#63483016), it seems that Kubernetes cannot manage LXC containers without LXD.
What I would like to know is:

1. Are there any container orchestration platforms like Kubernetes that can manage LXC containers?
2. Are there any existing service mesh implementations that can support LXC containers?

Any guidance or suggestions would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Referring to Can Kubernetes manage LXC containers without LXD daemon?,
> it seems that Kubernetes cannot manage LXC containers without LXD.

yeah, this is true..

> Are there any container orchestration platforms like Kubernetes that
> can manage LXC containers?

The only one(and I would say this is not full container orchestration platforms , but web UI) I ever saw is [lxdui](https://github.com/adaptivescale/lxdui), but again it requires LXD

> LXDUI is a visual interface for the LXD & LXC toolset. In order to use
> LXDUI you need to have LXD installed on your system. LXDUI leverages
> LXD's Python client library, pylxd, for interacting with the LXD REST
> API. It allows for rapid provisioning and management of large number
> of containers from a web browser, and you can simultaneously create
> any number of containers, even from multiple images, in one step.

> Are any existing service mesh implementations that can support LXC
> containers?

never met

Comment: Thank you for your response.